# Shell script returns: run.sh: line 10: SET: command not found

Tags: macos, bash, shell, meteor

I'm trying to run a shell script so I can boot up my local version of a Meteor app that I'm working on. I've never used shell scripts before this, but got the thing running when I was working with the head developer. So this is my **run.sh** file:

```
@echo off

c:

cd /Users/ten3/Desktop/git/ten/website/prospect-recovery/prospect-recovery

SET ROOT_URL=http://localhost

SET SPECIAL_RUN=no

SET NO_BATCH=no

SET NO_MAIL=no

SET MAIL_GUN_TEST=yes

SET MAIL_THROTTLE_INTERVAL=0

SET NODE_OPTIONS=%1

SET SHORT_URL=http://sota.ddns.net

SET NODE_PATH=%AppData%\npm

meteor --port 80

echo “works”
```

I'm pretty clueless as to what these actually do, aside from keep my local copy of the app interacting with other APIs. Every time I try to run the script I get:

```
run.sh: line 4: @echo: command not found
run.sh: line 6: c:: command not found
run.sh: line 10: SET: command not found
run.sh: line 12: SET: command not found
run.sh: line 14: SET: command not found
run.sh: line 16: SET: command not found
run.sh: line 18: SET: command not found
run.sh: line 20: SET: command not found
run.sh: line 22: SET: command not found
run.sh: line 24: SET: command not found
run.sh: line 26: SET: command not found
Error: listen EACCES                          
“works”
```

I've tried changing the file permissions, using sudo, tried including the file location in the paths it looks for it, tried including bash within my file, tried running the file inside the directory run.sh is, pretty much everything I can google. I can't figure out what I'm missing, and would like to die.

Comment: this script is intended for Windows

Comment: @user3159253 I was able to get it going on my mac previously, with help. My head developer uses windows.

Comment: This is a Windows batch script, not a Unix bash script.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem described could not be reproduced with a script genuinely written for a UNIX shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rewrite it for bash or another shell for a unix-like operating system (there're many alternatives, with `bash` is the most common).

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /some/required/path
ROOT_URL='http://localhost'
SPECIAL_RUN='no'
...
NODE_OPTIONS="$1" # notice double quotes, single quotes don't perform $variable expansion
SHORT_URL="http://sota.ddns.net"
NODE_PATH=/actual/path/to/npm
export ROOT_URL SPECIAL_RUN ... NODE_OPTIONS SHORT_URL NODE_PATH
./meteor --port 80 # since the port is below 1024, it's privileged, and the script should be run from root. Use ports > 1024 to run as a user
```

To run a program or a script from a given directory, you may specify a `/full/path/to/the/program` or simply include `/path/to/the` to `PATH`. By default current directory isn't in PATH for security reasons (unlike in Windows).

Comment: Ah okay. Does the bash script need to cd into my meteor app folder? Or is that only useful because then I could just start up my local server from there?

Comment: was the use of  ':c' and 'SET' dead giveaways that it was meant for windows?

Comment: yes, `c:` means you switch to the 'C:' volume. Unix-like systems have a single / with all volumes attached to a some point under `/` (see [man mount](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/mount.8.html))

Comment: Currently my run.sh file is located in: /Users/ten3 which I added to my path where it would look for that file using, export PATH=$PATH:/Users/ten3. So my run.sh file could be where it is, and I don't have to be in Users/ten3 to run it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96192/discussion-between-bart-dangus-and-user3159253).

Comment: I'd strongly suggest putting `|| exit` on the end of the `cd` -- otherwise, if it fails the rest of the script would continue to run.

Comment: I'd also suggest putting an `exec` on the last line: `exec ./meteor --port 80`; that way, the bash interpreter doesn't stick around in memory after `meteor` is invoked.

Comment: You might also consider `set -a`, to automatically export all shell variables assigned thereafter to the environment; that way, the `export` command doesn't need to be maintained with a separate list.